# SQL Insert erroring out

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am trying to run an insert to a table but my statements keep erroring out because I am using words like to and and inside them.

How can I get these paragraphs into the database?

```
INSERT INTO messages (message_title, message_content, from_user,
                      to_user, date, type, delivered, deleted)
VALUES('Dont forget to configure your profile!',
       'Welcome to the Club. The FIRST step to getting started is to set up your
        personal profile and your personal goals. You cant improve what you dont
        measure! Click on the following link and get your profile set up today.
        Set up my profile NOW. If you have any questions please be sure to contact
        our support team at info@support.com.',
       '1', '1', '2014-09-26', '0', '0', '0')
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: having "to" and "and" inside a string value will not break insert statements, please provide your error

Comment: What's the structure of the messages table?

Comment: data type for `message_content` should be `TEXT` OR `VARCHAR(1024)`

Comment: Not a reserved word problem... I was worried about date/type, but they're ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions about your schema here but am about to head out so wanted to post this to see if it helps:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1471/2

```
create table messages (message_title varchar(500), message_content varchar(8000), from_user int, to_user int, date datetime, type int, delivered bit, deleted bit);

INSERT INTO messages (message_title, message_content, from_user, to_user, date, type, delivered, deleted) 
VALUES(
'Dont forget to configure your profile!', 
'Welcome to the Club. The FIRST step to getting started is to set up your personal profile and your personal goals. You cant improve what you dont measure! 
    Click on the following link and get your profile set up today. Set up my profile NOW
    If you have any questions please be sure to contact our support team at info@support.com.',
'1', 
'1', 
'2014-09-26', 
'0', 
0, 
0);

select * from messages
```

I'm assuming here that your deleted and delivered columns are bit fields, when attempting to do an insert of a bit field with '1' instead of 1, the statement errors out.  As you can see by the fiddle, the (only slightly) modified insert statement does work.  So hopefully this will help you out!

Additionally, your other '1's i'm assuming are int columns, you don't need the quotes for inserting into those either.